# Passing address of iterator to function in STL::for_each

Tags: c++, function, stl, iterator

I have a function that I eventually want to parallelize.

Currently, I call things in a for loop.

```
double temp = 0;
int y = 123;  // is a value set by other code
for(vector<double>::iterator i=data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++){
    temp += doStuff(i, y);
}
```

doStuff needs to know *how far* down the list it is. So I use i - data.begin() to calculate.

Next, I'd like to use the stl::for_each function instead. My challenge is that I need to pass the *address* of my iterator *and* the value of y. I've seen examples of using bind2nd to pass a parameter to the function, but how can I pass the address of the iterator as the first parameter?

The boost FOREACH functions also looks like a possibility, however I do not know if it will parallelize auto-magically like the STL version does.

Thoughts, ideas, suggestions?

Comment: `std::accumulate` seems like a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want real parallelization here, use

- GCC with tree vectorization optimization on (-O3) and SIMD (e.g. -march=native to get SSE support). If the operation (dostuff) is non-trivial, you could opt to do it ahead of time (`std::transform` or `std::for_each`) and accumulate next (`std::accumulate`) since the accumulation will be optimized like nothing else on SSE instructions!

  ```
  void apply_function(double& value)
  {
       value *= 3; // just a sample...
  }

  // ...

  std::vector<double> data(1000);
  std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), &apply_function);
  double sum = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
  ```

**Note** that though this will not actually run on multiple threads, the performance increase will be massive since SSE4 instructions can handle many floating operations **in parallell* _on a single core_ .

If you wanted true parallelism, use one of the following

### [GNU Parallel Mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html)

Compile with `g++ -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL`:

```
__gnu_parallel::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0);
```

### [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) directly

Compile with `g++ -fopenmp`

```
double sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:sum)
for (size_t i=0; i<data.end(); i++)
{
    sum += do_stuff(i, data[i]);
}
```

This will result in the loop being parallelized into as many threads (OMP team) as there are (logical) CPU cores on the actual machine, and the result 'magically' combined and synchronized.

### Final remarks:

You can simulate the binary function for for_each by using a *stateful* function object. This is not exactly recommended practice. It will also appear to be very inefficient (when compiling without optimization, it is). This is due to the fact that function objects are passed by value thoughout the STL. However, it is reasonable to expect a compiler to completely optimize the potential overhead of that away, especially for simple cases like the following:

```
struct myfunctor
{
    size_t index; 
    myfunctor() : index(0) {}

    double operator()(const double& v) const
    {
        return v * 3; // again, just a sample
    }
};

// ...
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), myfunctor());
```

Comment: Sehe.  Awesome explanation.    Most of the work in my algorithm is fairly benign.  The doStuff step involves a few exponent operators and a few divisions, so that is the expensive part.  My plan is to parallelize that step so that I can take advantage of multiple cores.  Your suggestions on how to do this should prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`temp += doStuff( i, y );` cannot be auto parallelized.  The operator `+=` doesn't play well with concurrency.

Further the stl algorithms don't parallelize anything.  Both Visual Studio and GCC have parallel algorithms similar to `std::for_each`.  If that is what you're after you'll have to use those.

OpenMP can auto parallelize for loops, but you have to use pragmas to tell the compiler when and how (it can't figure it out for you).

You may have confused parallelization with loop unrolling, which is a common optimization in `std::for_each` implementations.

Comment: but the compiler will loop unroll the for-each version just as well as the STL version when optimizing

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward if you can change `doStuff` so that it takes the value of the current element separately from the index at which the current element is located.  Consider:

```
struct context {
    std::size_type _index;
    int            _y;
    double         _result;
};

context do_stuff_wrapper(context current, double value)
{
    current._result += doStuff(current._index, value, current._y);
    current._index++;
}

context c = { 0, 123, 0.0 };
context result = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), c, do_stuff_wrapper);
```

Note, however, that the Standard Library algorithms cannot "auto-parallelize" because the functions they call may have side effects (the compiler knows whether side effects are produced, but the library functions don't).  If you want a parallelized loop, you'll have to go with a special-purpose parallelizing algorithms library, like PPL or TBB.